# Regex that matches a word x times on a website

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a website page that we use which tests specific functions across an application of ours. It returns with "Success" on each line item of the site, for example:

```
Server1Name
Connection: Success
Process 1: Success
Process 2: Success 

Server2Name
Connection: Success
Process 1: Success
Process 2: Success

Server3Name
Connection: Success
Process 1: Success
Process 2: Success
```

What i'd like to do is find the word Success, 9 times on the page. What I've found thus far (in JavaScript) is:

```
((.|\n)*)(Success)
```

That matches the word Success throughout the page, including line breaks, etc however when I add:

```
{9}
```

to the end, to look like:

```
((.|\n)*)(Success){9}
```

it stops working. Any thoughts? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Why a regex? Why not just count occurances? And what if you have more than 9 matches?

Comment: JacaScript is the language and I need at least 9 matches (it can only report a max of 9 with the way the page is written anyways). @msarchet had the answer though, I was only wrapping the word Success in my expression...you need to wrap the whole qualifying expression for the count to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the whole match in ()

```
((.|\n)*)(Success)){9}
```

Comment: This is it! I actually just was playing around with it using Debuggex and found that I was only matching the word Success still.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is probably to count the total number of occurences and to check after if the number is greater than 8:

```
var numb = str.match(/\bSuccess\b/g).length;
if (numb>8) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Counting a String Match

This is an indirect answer to your question. You didn't specify a language in your original question, so rather than try to guess why you want to do what you're doing, I'm going to propose that you do something *simple* instead.

Assuming that your page is a file, or can be fed through a pipe to another command's standard input, you might consider using GNU grep to count fixed strings and then evaluate the result in your programming language of choice. For example, using the Bash shell:

```bash
success_count=$(grep --fixed-strings --count /path/to/file)
if (( success_count == 9 )); then
    true
else
    false
fi
```